# How I can get my array result without quotes

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I get my data in the table I have a array stocked as a string I want when I get this data I don't get it with '""' , and the second probleme I get it with slaches ! like the fonctionnalites.
this what I get

```
  {
        "id": 1,
        "icon": "/lsapp/public/projects/icon/1558102023logoMazad.png",
        "descriptions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris ",
        "fonctionnalites": "[\"CreativeDesign\",\"RetinaReady\",\"ModernDesign\",\"DigitalMarketingBranding\",\"rcveq\"]",
        "screenshoot": "[\"/lsapp/public/projects/screenshoot/1558102023mazad1.png\",\"/lsapp/public/projects/screenshoot/1558102023mazad2.png\",\"/lsapp/public/projects/screenshoot/1558102023mazad3.png\",\"/lsapp/public/projects/screenshoot/1558102023mazad4.png\"]",
    },
```

and I want get it like this

```
  {
        "id": 1,
        "icon": "/lsapp/public/projects/icon/1558102023logoMazad.png",
        "descriptions": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris ",
        "fonctionnalites": ["CreativeDesign","RetinaReady","ModernDesign","DigitalMarketingBranding","rcveq"],
        "screenshoot": ["/lsapp/public/projects/screenshoot/1558102023mazad1.png\","/lsapp/public/projects/screenshoot/1558102023mazad2.png","/lsapp/public/projects/screenshoot/1558102023mazad3.png","/lsapp/public/projects/screenshoot/1558102023mazad4.png"],
    },
```

and this what I do to get my result

```
public function getproject(Request $request)
{
    $services = WebProjects::all();
    return response()->json($services);
}
```

Comment: you mean without slashes right ?

Comment: without slaches and quotes , this how i get         "fonctionnalites": "[\"CreativeDesign\",\"RetinaReady\",\"ModernDesign\",\"DigitalMarketingBranding\",\"rcveq\"]",
and this is how i want get         "fonctionnalites": ["CreativeDesign","RetinaReady","ModernDesign","DigitalMarketingBranding","rcveq"],

Comment: @Cid is stored like what I want to get

Comment: What is the data type of `fonctionnalites` and `screenshoot` columns? `varchar`?

Comment: String , can i change it to get the correct result?

Comment: You can use `json` data type to store arrays in the DB. And add cast to an array in your model.

Comment: I don't unterstand how I can do this

Comment: Can you show your plain data from the DB?

Comment: [Change column type in migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns)

Comment: I suspect a poorly designed DB. Think about normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your members `fonctionnalites` and `screenshoot` are already json encoded.

```
// in this example, the sub array "toto" is an encoded array
$arr = ["foo" => "bar", "toto" => json_encode(["forty", "two"])];
echo json_encode($arr); // outputs : {"foo":"bar","toto":"[\"forty\",\"two\"]"}
```

You can decode it first, before re-encoding the whole array/object

```
$arr = ["foo" => "bar", "toto" => json_encode(["forty", "two"])];
echo json_encode($arr); //{"foo":"bar","toto":"[\"forty\",\"two\"]"}

$arr["toto"] = json_decode($arr["toto"]);
echo json_encode($arr); //{"foo":"bar","toto":["forty","two"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
return response()->json($services, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

if you have non-encoded string data in the database.

[Reference to json flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) and how [flags are used in Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php#L27).

By the way, Laravel [understands](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php#L32) when Collection is returned as a response and serializes it, you can go just with `return $services;`.

P. S. Take a look on [Cid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220671/9506712), if your data is already encoded and stored as string in the database.

Comment: i get the same result

Comment: Do you have casts to array in the Model? Any accessors are defined?